# Como instalar una version especifica de node js en ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, npm, docker, curl

Estoy usando Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS #Docker FROM phusion/passenger-ruby25:0.9.33

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y utilizo los siguientes comandos:

```
# Configure NVM & NPM dependencies
apt-get install -y nodejs
apt-get install -y npm
npm config set strict-ssl false


npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n 8

npm install --global mjml@3.3.5 yarn
```

Y necesito la version 8 de nodej
Pero:

```
Node -v >> 8.17.0
npm -v >> 6.13
nodejs -v >> 4.2.6
```

Necesito instalar la versión 8 de nodejs
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: al intentarlo por curl me bota un error.

Comment: Tal vez te sirva la comunidad de [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), tienen muchas preguntas relacionadas a la tuya. Por ejemplo [esta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169439/install-downgrade-specific-version-of-node-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar NVM (Node Version Manager)

Me gusta este opción porqué instalar una versión de node esta tan fácil como escribir un comando.

Descargar el repositorio:

```
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
```

Ejecuta el script:

```
bash install_nvm.sh
```

Dicho script actualiza el ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, o ~/.bashrc, si estas en ubuntu el script te actualiza el .bashrc pero para confirma escribe el siguiente comando para saber que archivo se actualizo:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Actualiza la terminal con el archivo que se actualizo.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Cierra y verifica que NVM esta instalado

```
command -v nvm
```

O

```
nvm -v
```

Instala la versión especifica que necesitas

```
nvm install 8
```

Fuente

- https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/
- https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

Comment: Nota: esta aproximación no es muy feliz en máquinas de C.I. u otros procesos automáticos, porque depende enteramente de que cargue las variables de entorno correctas, etc. y las ejecuciones programáticas pueden tener líos.